# Query regarding examples of motional EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

**Question:**  Is the reason that it is stated that $f_{pull} = uB$ to counteract the magnetic force $quB$ to the left, rather than $f_{pull} \geq uB$, because we are modelling for one instant of time where we are calculating the force required per unit charge by assuming that the circuit is moving at constant velocity $\vec{v}$ to the right?

[image]
[image]
[image: Image referred to in comment]

Comment: Yes you are right. Even if we exert a greater force, the speed of the loop to the right increases which increases the magnetic force experienced by the particles. This increases their speed in the upward direction and thereby  the magnetic force to the left. Thus the force required to pull the loop becomes equal to the force which we were applying.

Comment: @cobra121 Okay thanks. Would I also be correct in stating that in the first  (Figure 7.10), the emf only drives current located in wire $a$ to $b$ as only the charge located in the area in the magnetic field (shaded) experiences the magnetic force? Or does the current run through the whole circuit? I attached another example (labelled figure 7.15), where there is a turning disk. I don't see why the current runs down the wires once the charge is off the disk (I understand how they calculate the emf)?

Comment: Is there some induced electric field (as in the case of a stationary circuit with a battery) causing the current to run or is it the charges knocking against each other or something like that? Thanks a lot for assistance, I'm studying independently (not a registered student) so it helps discussing these things.

Comment: The EMF is due to the free charges in the wire $a$ to $b$, but the current runs through the entire circuit. I don't understand how can the current only run in $a$ to $b$

Comment: For the disk imagine a line from the center to the point where the sliding contact is connected. Then that line along with the rest of the circuit below the disk form a conventional circuit. Now it's easy to see why charge runs down the circuit.

Comment: There is no 'induced' electric field. Induced electric field usually refers to the non conservative field formed due a change in magnetic field in time. Here the magnetic field is constant. Motional EMF is purely due to the magnetic force . Imagine a straight rod moving at a some velocity to the right and a magnetic field pointing into the plane of the rod. Then there will be a charge separation in the rod as positive charges go up and negative charges go down. This is similar to a capacitor. If we connect a wire across a capacitor it discharges and so does the rod.

Comment: But the rod's voltage is maintained as we keep moving it to the right. Now there is an electric field in the rest of the circuit due to separation of charges,but that field is a conservative one. Also another interesting thing is that in the reference frame moving to the right at the same velocity, there is no magnetic force on the charges and still there is an EMF.